# Как получить элементы (с 1-го по посл.) из временной таблицы?

Tags: sql, plsql

Есть функция которая возвращает период(интервал) выходных дней

```
GET_PREV_HOLIDAY('to_date('21/05/18','dd/mm/yyyy')',vd_datebeg,vd_dateend);
```

Функция возвращает `vd_datebeg = 19/05/18 vd_dateend = 21/05/18`
Т.е возвращает интервал 19 -21 (с субботы по понедельник)
Как перечислить(получить) только выходные дни : 19/05/18 и 20/05/18
Мой код:

```
vd_date1 := vd_datebeg;  
--запишем все выходные даты во вр таблицу
    while vd_date1 < vd_dateend loop
        date_table(i):=vd_date1;
        vd_date1 := vd_date1 + 1;
        i := i+1;
    end loop;
```

На выходе нужно получить даты `19/05/18 и 20/05/18`

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего, имхо, использовать `to_char` с форматом `d`:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'd') from dual
```

В этом случае функция возвращает номер дня недели. Выходные дни будут иметь номера `6` и `7` (тут надо помнить о региональных настройках: у американцев воскресенье - первый день недели). В итоге для диапазона дат понадобится примерно такой запрос:

```
select weekend
  from (select vd_datebeg + rownum - 1 weekend
          from dual
        connect by level <= (vd_datebeg - vd_dateend))
 where to_char(weekend, 'd') in (6, 7)
```